# How do you make text and variable in haml appear on same line?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I have this code and I want it to read as Volunteers Needed: 10 (event.numberofvolunteers value) on the same line. How can I do this without using css? I haven't found a specific post addressing this issue.

```
%td Volunteers Needed:
  = event.numberofvolunteers
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
%td= "Volunteers Needed: #{event.numberofvolunteers}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Best way to write this would be :

```
%td Volunteers Needed: #{event.numberofvolunteers}
```